# Desktop Applications Using Java Connected with SQL database server

Tags: java, sql-server, database, desktop-application

I was asked to develop a desktop application for a small company that has many branches in different locations. From my little experience I have to deploy a desktop application that will be connected to database server.

### System Requirements

1. Desktop application with a good UI.
2. Database to handle all the company data.
3. Login panel - each employee will have his own user/pass to access the authorized information that he will have the capability to access.
4. Querying the data from the database to be viewed on the UI

### What I can do and what I will use

- First I will use Java and SQL database to implement this project as I have a good experience in both.
- I have no idea what the implementation flow will be. What should I do first -- The logic, the database, or the GUI?
- Also, I didn't use servers before, so I don't know how the connection between the desktop application and the database server will be established.

### What I'm seeking

- I need the guidelines (the key points) for which I will use this project and if there are few resources, I would be grateful.
- Also I need to know what technology I should use.

Comment: Do the branches have their own copies of the database or they connect to the central office?

Comment: @RomanC Thanks for your reply, The co and all the branches share the same database. They are all access the same info and the info maybe updated anytime from any branch or the co itself. So the availability and the integrity is also important

Comment: Another important  thing is how branches communicate to the CO, do they use local network, VPN, public network?

Comment: @RomanC they will use the internet as they are settled in different locations

Comment: Internet is a public network, the best for you is to implement RESTful web services to access the database and write http client application.

Comment: @RomanC So how other desktop applications that have the same requirements ( many branches in different locations ) share the same database ?. Isn't it via a database server and only the desktop application users can access this server via the application

Comment: I guessed you knew that because you said you had good experience in both java and database, hope you don't need to connect to the cloud to access your database.

Comment: @RomanC i had a good experience in both java and database i used them alone as a unit but i have never tried to implement such thing. In fact i need to connect the cloud to access the database, but why you don't hope so ?

Comment: I don't have experience with cloud architectures, so I can't help you with it.

Comment: Upvote for the good, detailed question, but close vote for too broad, sorry.

Comment: If you really want more detailed answers, http://serverfault.com/ might be the more appropriate place to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one data warehouse for the servers that all branches access. There is no need for managing and syncing separate database servers.

You could do that pretty easily by starting, for example, a (free) micro Amazon EC2 instance to get started, install your SQL server software on it, then simply use the IP address of that server to do your connections.

If you are having many connections to this server and a lot of data to store between these branches, then you will need to start paying for this server. You can read more about [Amazon EC2 Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) if you wish.

As far as what to start on first, obviously get the schemas for you database tables established before starting to store data. After that, the logic is more important than the GUI. If you are not a User Interface person, move all the GUI stuff until the end. End users truly care more about functionality than a good UI.

I do have a small question, you have experience both the Java and SQL, but never used a server before? Those statements contradict each other if you used Java to connect to the SQL *server*.

The technology you should be using is a Java Database Connectivity (JDBC), but as @RomanC was mentioning in the comments, you really should setup a REST API around your database on the server using whatever server-side language you are comfortable with. This is allow you to "sanitize" the inputs of your data more cleanly, restricting direct access to your database, and allows more extensible method calls and functionality on top of direct SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I would do:

1. Will implement application in agile methodology. Choose a use case and implement it through. For example if you want users to login. Start thinking about the components to build to implement it, I.e. start thinking about users table in database, a DAO layer to access database, create a service layer to manage business logic and view layer to display data and to receive users input. I am suggesting layered architecture as the code would be easy to manage and enhance and in future if you will have to make it a web application, it won't take much to do so.
   And most importantly, practice TDD approach in your project and you will be fine.
   I hope that will help.